# How to filter "???" sign using sparql?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have to data like following:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://ru.dbpedia.org/resource/??????????????_??????????">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://sv.dbpedia.org/resource/Ställdon">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://tr.dbpedia.org/resource/Aktüatör">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://uk.dbpedia.org/resource/??????????_????????">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://zh.dbpedia.org/resource/???">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator"/>
```

I want to filter data ??????????_????????. How do i filter out this data?

Following is the query

```
CONSTRUCT {
    <http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Actuator> ?p ?o.
    ?s2 ?p2 <http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Actuator>
} WHERE  {
    {
        <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator> ?p ?o
    } UNION {
        ?s2 ?p2 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator>
    }
    FILTER regex(str(?s2),"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator$","i")
}
```

Comment: I expect that those aren't question marks, but characters in IRIs that your browser/terminal/etc., isn't displaying properly.  But we can't really help you add a filter unless you show us the query that you used.  Can you include your query?

Comment: As I mentioned, it looks like it's just a matter of the IRIs containing things that your system isn't displaying correctly. You could filter out everything doesn't start with `http://dbpedia.org/`;  would you be willing to eliminate `http://sv.dbpedia.org/resource/Ställdon` too?

Comment: yes i want only Actuator will return the reuslt

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your query explicitly constructs triples with a different subject.

Comment: the query return only <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Actuator">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Actuator"/>
</rdf:Description>

Comment: That *is* the object of all those triples though; exactly what your query asked for. What do you *actually want*? Be specific.

Answer (score 2):

How about somethign like this:

```sql
construct {
  <http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Actuator> ?p1 ?o1.
  ?s2 ?p2 <http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Actuator>
}
where {
 {
   dbpedia:Actuator ?p1 ?o1
   #-- Either ?o1 must be a non-IRI, or it must be an IRI that doesn't start 
   #-- with http://XX.dbpedia.org/ (i.e., a localized resource).
   filter( !isIRI(?o1) || !regex(str(?o1),"http://[a-z]+.dbpedia.org/" ) )
 } 
 union
 {
  ?s2 ?p2 dbpedia:Actuator
  filter strstarts( str(?s2), "http://dbpedia.org/" )
 }
}
```